# asp.net open source projects

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Wanted to know which open source projects (eg blog engine.net, etc) is good to explore/read its source code.

The main purpose is to help a beginner `ASP.NET /C#` developer learn about how to code the presentation/business/data layers cleanly.

One `ASP.NET` for `Webforms`.  Maybe another for `ASP.NET MVC`.  Preferably for .NET Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest viewing this post which list the [best .net open source projects of 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365263/whats-your-favorite-c-open-source-project-of-the-year-2008)

Alternatively, Scott Gu (a must read for any .Net developer) commented on [Microsoft's Web Platform Installer](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/06/02/microsoft-web-platform-installer.aspx) a tool which lets you easily install web platform components including a number of excellent and useful example sites.

Finally, for the ultimate example of cutting edge .NET 3.5 technology, check out the open source project called [Nerd Diner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/).  It is MS sponsored but still open source and was created to display the very best in .Net development practices.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see this 2 projects in the list,

- [cuyahoga](http://www.cuyahoga-project.org/)
- [mojo-portal](http://www.mojoportal.com/)

2 ASP.NET projects...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to develop your coding skills is to participate and contribute.

Here is an open source ERP solution ["MixERP"](http://mixerp.org) that is based on ASP.net(C#) webforms and PostgreSQL being developed over at [GitHub](http://github.com/binodnp/mixerp) and is looking for contributions.

Go ahead, get your hands dirty and enjoy learning.